# Is this JPA query vulnerable to SQL injection?

Tags: java, sql, jpa, sql-injection

I have a library that executes a query based on a JPA WHERE statement provided by a caller. I am executing the following JPA query:

```
public void executeQuery(String jpaWhereStatement) {
String queryString = "SELECT entity FROM " + MyEntity.class.getSimpleName() + " entity WHERE " + jpaWhereStatement;
}
```

The query parameters are still inserted using `query.setParameter()`, but I am worried I might be allowing a SQL injection attack. If this is vulnerable, how can I fix this code?

Comment: see: http://www.adam-bien.com/roller/abien/entry/preventing_injection_in_jpa_query

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Without knowing much about the caller, it's difficult to say. It's *possible* there is a vulnerability there if your where statement is not generated carefully. In general, this approach looks like a bad idea to me. I would, personally, be more explicit about how you're generating that WHERE clause and always use parameters.

As a general rule, never trust any data being used to construct a SQL statement, whether it comes from the client or it comes from the DB.

Answer (score 1):

As bunting pointed out(and Adam Bien as well), if you stick to parametrized queries, you should be golden. Of course if there are general vulnerabilities present in your implementation, then you could be at risk.

Answer (score 0):

As a rule of thumb, when user input or input from a GET are involved, use Criteria to make sure parameters are escaped. I.E. DO NOT USE HQL.

If user input or input from get is not involved you can use HQL.

But yes, if you use `setParamter()` there is *probably* no sql injection problem.

Comment: I was about to +1 you for the first two paragraphs, but I couldn't after your last sentence.  If the `jpaWhereStatement` can be manipulated by a malicious user, then it doesn't matter that other query parameters are inserted using `query.setParameter()`.

Comment: Hmm.. one of us mis-read the question, if the `jpaWhereStatement` is constructed but no values inserted in the string, instead placeholders for the values are used and then `setParameter()` method of the `Query` object is used to set the values (as I thought the question implied), shouldn't hibernate escape all the input? There would be no threat.

Comment: It's possible I misread the question.  My point was, if there is *any* possibility that a malicious user can affect the way `jpaWhereStatement` is constructed (the most egregious example would be if `jpaWhereStatement` includes text that came directly from a URL parameter, but more subtle attacks are at least theoretically possible), then `setParameter()` isn't enough.  If *every* string that can possibly have been touched by the user only ever affects `setParameter()` and not `jpaWhereStatement`, then you're right, it's probably safe.  But I'm not certain that's the case here.